# Avoid Laravel redirect after validation

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation, form-data

I'm making a simple validation on my Laravel controller:

```php
public function updateInfo(Request $request) {

        $validator = $request->validate([
            "name" => ["string", "nullable"],
            "email" => ["email", "nullable"],
            "currentPassword" => ["password:api"]
        ]);

        return json_encode($validator);
}
```

My problem is that this validation redirects me to the home if fails, and i'm making the request via AJAX, i know that Laravel detects when a request is via Ajax, but it only works if is a normal request (the typical request in which i send the headers with `Content Type application/json` and in the body i sent a normal JSON

But Laravel is not able of detect when te Ajax request is not of `Content Type application/json`, i'm using the `FormData()` object of JavaScript, so, i don't sent the header `Content Type application/json`, and in the body i sent the FormData object.

I think it's simulate a typical HTTP request reloading the page, and for that reason Laravel is not able of detect it, but it gives me troubles with the ajax response because Laravel response the redirect and in my Ajax response i'm catching the HTML Code of the home page.

What can i do?

Comment: Use a manual Validator: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators You'll have complete control on what to do with the validation if it fails.

Comment: I tried it, now i can catch the errors, but now when i use `$validator->errors()->all()` to get the errors array, it only gives me the key of the error: `["validation.password"]` but the message is not present, do you have any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, as the Validator class is a little odd. `$validator->errors()` (without the `->all()`) should return what you're looking for I think? For reference, the Validator and MessageBag classes are what's being used here: https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Validation/Validator.html and https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html (via `$validator->errors()`)

Comment: Yes, but it returns an array with the array with the key, i found the problem, i didn't have defined that index on my lang files, thanks!!!

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense! Btw, my comment was just to point you in the correct direction; you should post your solution as an answer, or, if one of the solutions below helped, consider upvoting them and/or accepting one of them (which you did, cheers!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `validator()` helper function with `validate()` method it will help you with both AJAX calls and normal calls

```
validator($request->all(), [
    "name" => ["string", "nullable"],
    "email" => ["email", "nullable"],
    "currentPassword" => ["password:api"]
])->validate();
```